# SFX For Strippers

Tags: cars, engine, sfx, sound-effects

Hey All,

Next week we will be beginning tracklaying for a new series called Strippers. Unfortunately  this has nothing to do with women taking their clothes off but actually cars being stripped and tuned.

I need to source some accurate sound effects for specific cars taking into consideration auto and manual gearboxes. Could anyone recommend a good source for these? Below is a list of the cars.

1996 Mitsubishi Evo 4
2002 Subaru Impreza WRX STI

2001 Mini Cooper manual
1985 Austin Mini 1000 manual

1989 Land Rover 2.5 Diesel manual
1989 Mitsubishi Shogun/Pajero 2.5 Turbo Diesel automatic

1984 Porsche 944 2.5 manual
1998 Alfa Romeo 2.0 twin spark petrol manual

1976 MGB GT 1.8 manual
1991 Mazda MX5 1.6 manual (Eunos Roadster)

1986 VW Transporter T25 1.9 petrol manual (water cooled)
1975 VW Beetle 1303 manual

1987 VW Golf GTI 16V
1987 Ford Escort XR3i (1.6i) Cabriolet manual

1997 Audi A8 2.8 petrol auto
1999 Jaguar XJR V8 Supercharged

1984 Corvette 5.7 V8 auto
1993 Ford Thunderbird 3.8 V6 Supercharged auto

Rolls Royce Silver Shadow – Mid 1970s
Jaguar XJ6 – mid 1980s

Thanks!

Comment: Haha nice title, I've a recording of the servo thing that opens the textile roof in my cousin's convertible mini cooper if that could help at all?

Comment: @Sonny contact max(at)pole.se - he records cars for a living, he might have what you are after. if not, might know who has -

Comment: Cheers Stephen that would probably come in handy! Could you email it to me via sonny@sonnylota.com. I owe you a pint!

Comment: Hi Redsonic01 thanks I have just emailed him!